# How calculate integration of multiplying two-looped function in matlab

Tags: matlab, integral, function-handle

I have a function that changes by loop , as below

```
f(x,y)=(i-1)*x+(j-1)*y
g(x,y)=(i+1)*x+(j+1)*y
```

The real function is more Complex than this, however/

I want to calculate the integration of `f(x,y)*g(x,y)` when `i` & `j` are changed by the loop.

I want to calculate like below in `matlab`, but this code isn't correct.

```
for i=1:n
for j=1:n
h=@(x,y)(f*g) % f & g are functions
int=integral2(h,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax);
end
end


function m=f(x,y,i,j)
m=(i-1)*x+(j-1)*y
end
```

Comment: You need to explain why it isn't correct, what the results are, and what the expected results are.

Comment: well i don't know how to use function handle for looped functions & how to calculate them. i just wrote this code to say what i want to do.